# Sort CSV file by count on column values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting

May I know how I can sort a csv file by a certain column, not by the value in the column, but the count of rows having the largest number of same values should appear first (or last).

Is it possible to do this using csv package or pandas. If I can see both that will be great.

I hope I have described the problem in an understandable manner

Comment: You can do that, You need to first get count for each of the values, from there you can assign reference index for the value based on the count, then you can add that index as a new column to the dataframe, finally sort the values on those newly added column, finally drop those added columns.

Comment: A worked example in your question would help

Answer (score 1):

With **pandas** you can combine using **key** parameter of `sort_values()` and a **lambda** function that effectively calculates the frequency.

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":np.random.choice(list("abcd"),20,p=(.46,.46,.04,.04))})
df.sort_values("col", key=lambda s: s.groupby(s).transform("size"))
```

#### output

|  | col |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 1 | a |
| 16 | a |
| 5 | a |
| 15 | a |
| 8 | a |
| 13 | a |
| 11 | a |
| 17 | b |
| 14 | b |
| 12 | b |
| 9 | b |
| 18 | b |
| 7 | b |
| 6 | b |
| 4 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 10 | b |
| 19 | b |